# sql server compare two column from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table containing one columns in both table

table1
item

table2
item

I want a boolean result true/false if all the values in item column of table1 and table2 are exact match.
e.g columns values for both table

```
item     item
apple    apple
boy      boy
cat      cat
```

this should return true

```
item     item
apple    apple
boy      boy
cat      dog
```

should return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if records exist on one side or the other only by joining the two tables left-to-right and right-to-left.  If there are any records not matched, it's `false`, otherwise `true`.

```
select case when exists (
    select top 1 1
    from Table1 t1
    left join Table2 t2 on t2.item = t1.item
    where t2.item is null
    
    union all

    select top 1 1
    from Table2 t2
    left join Table1 t1 on t1.item = t2.item
    where t1.item is null
) 
    THEN 'false'
    ELSE  'true'
END as result
```

Comment: This is not working if the order of items are changed, means if we have apple, boy in t1 and boy apple in t2,query returns false, it should return true.
Can you please update the query

Comment: This works regardless of the order of the items.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f57b/1/0.  I updated the query to match the column name from your question (`item`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `full join` and aggregation:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'true' else 'false' end)
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.item = t2.item
where t1.item is null or t2.item is null;
```

This counts misses.  If there are none, then the tables are the same.

Or without the `where` clause:

```
select (case when count(t1.item) = count(t2.item) then 'true' else 'false' end)
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.item = t2.item
where t1.item is null or t2.item is null;
```

Note:  Like the data in your question, and the question in general, this assumes that the items are unique.